# Is it possible to emulate behavior of \XeTeXuseglyphmetrics in luatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, font-metrics

The \XeTeXuseglyphmetrics feature of XeTeX is handy when typesetting content that is to be placed side-by-side while trying to adhere to a baseline grid. This is because \XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0 forces the XeTeX engine to consider each character to have same height & depth, thus making the baseline placement agnostic of max. character height in first line of text. How (if at all) can this be achieved in lualatex?

Comment: `\topskip` should be set such that the first baseline does not depend on any normal characters in the font, so you shouldn't see a difference in placement due to this setting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for this answer, yes it had worked :) I completely forgot getting back to you on this. That was because I was thinking to do a working example to be posted here, and forgot. If that is not required by the guidelines of this forum, please feel free to copy your comment as answer & I will accept that, and I can add a working example later for others to benefit.